# How to get data from node backend to react frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

I am creating a web app that uses react on the frontend and node on the backend. On the backend a web hook is used to get information about the status of a Twilio conference. Whenever the status changes, it gets posted to an endpoint on my backend. How do I get that information to the front end without constantly polling?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are looking for [WebSockets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-are-websockets), which are a constant connection between a front-end and back-end that you can send data over. If you are working with Node.js then you might find a library like [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) a helpful introduction to working with WebSockets. There is a tutorial for [building a simple chat](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) that will take you through the basics that you can then apply to this problem.